# How to add a different coloured line to a pandas plot with defined colourmap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot 4 graphs in one diagram where three of the lines should use a specific colourmap and one line a colour not within that map. Here is a sample code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

plt.style.use('ggplot')
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 0.0, 10],[87, 32, 161],[821, 271, 804],[246, 922, 819],[107, 785, 1697]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
data_cost = pd.DataFrame(index=[2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005], data=[[4],[311],[671],[862], [593]], columns=['D'])
my_cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("GnBu_d", 3).as_hex())
ax = data.plot(colormap=my_cmap, alpha=0.8, rot=0, xticks=data.index,
               linewidth=6, ylim=(-0.5, 20), ax=ax)
ax = data.plot(colormap=my_cmap, rot=0, xticks=data.index, marker='s', ms=15, linewidth=6, ylim=(-0.5, 13), ax=ax)
ax = data_cost.plot(color='r', rot=0, xticks=data_cost.index,
                    linewidth=6, ylim=(1000, 5000), marker='s', ms=15, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('I', fontsize=40)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=40)
ax.set_xlabel('Y', fontsize=40)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=40)
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), fontsize=40, prop={'size':32})
ax.set_facecolor('none')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately this seems not to work. If I remove the ax in the plots it looks better. But how can I achieve this? At the end I would like to have the following plot, where just one line is read:

[image]

with `D` as a red curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be quite a few problems with your code. Please find below my edited version, which should bring the plot quite close to what you post in your question. I guess the biggest problem was the contradicting `ylim` arguments in the plot commands and the missing index in the Dataframe "data". Note that the `fontsize=40` increases the text quite much out of proportion, which is why I commented them out. If this is desired anyway, you should try experimenting from there.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.style.use('ggplot')
data = pd.DataFrame(index=[2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005], data=[[1, 0.0, 10],[87, 32, 161],[821, 271, 804],[246, 922, 819],[107, 785, 1697]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
data_cost = pd.DataFrame(index=[2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005], data=[[4],[311],[671],[862], [593]], columns=['D'])
my_cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette("GnBu_d", 3).as_hex())
##ax = data.plot(colormap=my_cmap, alpha=0.8, rot=0, xticks=data.index,
##               linewidth=6,
##               #ylim=(-0.5, 20),
##               ax=ax)
ax = data.plot(colormap=my_cmap, rot=0, xticks=data.index,
               marker='s', ms=15, linewidth=6,
               #ylim=(-0.5, 13),
               ax=ax
               )
ax = data_cost.plot(color='r', rot=0, xticks=data_cost.index,
                    linewidth=6,
                    #ylim=(1000, 5000),
                    marker='s', ms=15, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('I')#, fontsize=40)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params()#labelsize=40)
ax.set_xlabel('Y')#, fontsize=40)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params()#labelsize=40)
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
ax.legend(
    loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),
    #fontsize=40,
    prop={'size':32})
ax.set_facecolor('none')
#plt.show()
fig.savefig('example.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The final figure looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]